# translate a php script to c# httpClient

Tags: c#, php, curl, httpclient

I need help translating a sample PHP code into C # code. The existing documentation is unfortunately very poorly described and only designed for PHP. However, I need access through the C # HttpClient. My current c # testscript transfers the data in a json serialized json model. This works too. But as soon as I try to transfer the file, I get an error message. In the PHP script the file is simply added, I think it is simply transferred as a byte []. If I try to transfer the file as a byte [] I get an error 500. If I try to transfer the file as a multipart, I get a forbidden. How do I have to transfer the file correctly so that it is accepted by the REST API. Unfortunately, the tests are always a bit difficult because I always have to call the manufacturer and ask whether everything has now been transferred correctly. The manufacturer always only refers to the doku and the curl script, which is now working.
So the primary question would now be how does CURLFILE work and what does the command return?

In the database, the field type is just an attachment. Unfortunately I don't have more information here.

Can anyone help?

**Update**

I have now looked at the CURLFILE in the PHP documentation. Here will

- name
- mime
- postname
  passed

The mime type is application / octet-stream

**PHP Script**

```
<?php

$data = '{
        "username": "xx",
        "password": "hgertr"
    }';

$headers = [
    'Accept: application/json',
    'Content-Type: application/json',
];

$url = 'https:/xxx/sessions';

$curlHandle = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curlHandle, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($curlHandle, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curlHandle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curlHandle, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($curlHandle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 20);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curlHandle, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'C:\cookie');

$response = curl_exec($curlHandle);

$code = curl_getinfo($curlHandle, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

if ($code === 201) {
    $response = json_decode($response, true);
    $sessionId = $response['sessions'][0]['sessionId'];
} else {
    echo 'Fehler beim Authentifizieren: ' . $code;
    var_export($response);
    var_export(curl_error($curlHandle));
}

curl_reset($curlHandle);


$fileForFirstRow = new CURLFile('abc.pdf');


$inputData = [
    'step' => '10',
    'subtables[0][name]' => 'ST_SR_PDF',
   
    'subtables[0][rows][0][fields][0][name]' => 'DEADLINE',
    'subtables[0][rows][0][fields][0][value]' => 15,
    'subtables[0][rows][0][fields][1][name]' => 'DOC_DESC',
    'subtables[0][rows][0][fields][1][value]' => 'wert1',
    'subtables[0][rows][0][fields][2][name]' => 'DOC',
    'subtables[0][rows][0][fields][2][value]' => $fileForFirstRow,

    
    'subtables[1][name]' => 'ST_SR_USER', 
    'subtables[1][rows][0][fields][0][name]' => 'SIGNATORY_PRE_NAME',
    'subtables[1][rows][0][fields][0][value]' => 'hans',
    'subtables[1][rows][0][fields][1][name]' => 'SIGNATORY_LAST_NAME',
    'subtables[1][rows][0][fields][1][value]' => 'wert1',
   
];
curl_reset($curlHandle);

curl_setopt($curlHandle, CURLOPT_URL,
    'https://xxx.xx/jr_signature_rest');
curl_setopt($curlHandle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curlHandle, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($curlHandle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $inputData);
curl_setopt($curlHandle, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'C:\cookie');

$response = curl_exec($curlHandle);
$statusCode = curl_getinfo($curlHandle, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
```

My current c # code.

**c#**

```
 using (var client = new HttpClient()) {
   client.DefaultRequestHeaders
   .Accept
   .Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

    string fileName = "e:\\xxx.pdf";
    byte[] buff = File.ReadAllBytes(fileName);

    string workflowID = "";
                
    LoginInformation loginInformation = new LoginInformation();
    loginInformation.username = "xx";
    loginInformation.password = "xdsf";

    var LoginAsString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(loginInformation);

var LoginDataContent = new StringContent(LoginAsString,Encoding.UTF8,"application/json");

     HttpResponseMessage result = await client.PostAsync("xx/sessions", LoginDataContent);

  var fieldlist = new List<DokFields>();

  
  fieldlist.Add(new DokFields { name = "DEADLINE", value = 28 });
  fieldlist.Add(new DokFields { name = "DOC_DESC", value = "VERTRAG" });
  fieldlist.Add(new DokFields { name = "DOC_NAME", value = "xxx.pdf" });
  fieldlist.Add(new DokFields { name = "DOC_TYPE", value = 2 });
  fieldlist.Add(new DokFields { name = "SIGNATURE_TYPE", value = 2 });
  fieldlist.Add(new DokFields { name = "SMS_OTP", value = 0 });
  fieldlist.Add(new DokFields { name = "DOC", value = buff) });




  DokFieldList jsonFields = new DokFieldList();
  jsonFields.fields = fieldlist;

  var jsonFieldsList = new List<DokFieldList>();

  jsonFieldsList.Add(jsonFields);

  var SubtablesList = new List<Subtables>();
  Subtables subtable_ST_SR_PDF = new Subtables();
  subtable_ST_SR_PDF.name = "ST_SR_PDF";
  subtable_ST_SR_PDF.rows = jsonFieldsList;
  SubtablesList.Add(subtable_ST_SR_PDF);


  var UserList = new List<Field>();
  var UserFelderPartner1 = new List<DBFeld>();
  UserFelderPartner1.Add(new DBFeld { name = "SIGNATORY_PRE_NAME", value = "pre 1" });
   UserFelderPartner1.Add(new DBFeld { name = "SIGNATORY_LAST_NAME", value = "last 1" });
  UserFelderPartner1.Add(new DBFeld { name = "SIGNATORY_MAIL", value = "xxxx" });
  UserFelderPartner1.Add(new DBFeld { name = "MOBILE_SMS_OTP", value = "yyyyyy" });
  Field P1 = new Field();
  P1.fields = UserFelderPartner1;
  UserList.Add(P1);


  var SubtableUserList = new List<SubtablesUser>();
  SubtablesUser subtable_ST_SR_USER = new SubtablesUser();
  subtable_ST_SR_USER.name = "ST_SR_USER";
  subtable_ST_SR_USER.rows = UserList;

  SubtableUserList.Add(subtable_ST_SR_USER);

  List<Object> all = (from x in SubtablesList select (Object)x).ToList();
   all.AddRange((from x in SubtableUserList select (Object)x).ToList());


 Step step = new Step();
 step.step = 10;
 step.subtables = all;

 var stepsAsString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(step);
 var stepsContent = new StringContent(stepsAsString, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
                        

 HttpResponseMessage responseSteps = await client.PostAsync("xxx/jr_signature_rest", stepsContent);
}
```

If I run the script without the line with the file upload, the data is correctly transferred to the REST API and the values are also available. If I try to let the data run with the file upload, the server returns a server error 500.

`fieldlist.Add(new DokFields { name = "DOC", value = buff) });`

**Upload Data c#**

The transferred data as json.

```
{"step":10,"subtables":[{"name":"ST_SR_PDF","rows":[{"fields":[{"name":"DEADLINE","value":28},{"name":"DOC_DESC","value":"VERTRAG"},{"name":"DOC_NAME","value":"xxx.pdf"},{"name":"DOC_TYPE","value":2},{"name":"SIGNATURE_TYPE","value":2},{"name":"SMS_OTP","value":0},{"name":"DOC","value":"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...more Data...hcnR4cmVmCjg0MDA2CiUlRU9GCg=="}]}]},{"name":"ST_SR_USER","rows":[{"fields":[{"name":"SIGNATORY_PRE_NAME","value":"pre 1"},{"name":"SIGNATORY_LAST_NAME","value":"last 1"},{"name":"SIGNATORY_MAIL","value":"xxxx"},{"name":"MOBILE_SMS_OTP","value":"yyyyyy"}]},{"fields":[{"name":"SIGNATORY_PRE_NAME","value":"pre 2"},{"name":"SIGNATORY_LAST_NAME","value":"last  2"},{"name":"SIGNATORY_MAIL","value":"xxxx"},{"name":"MOBILE_SMS_OTP","value":"yyyyy"}]}]}]}
```

Comment: Please format your code to be readable and not indented so much (nor inconsistently indented).

Comment: Thank you for improving your question, but your formatting is still broken: you have a broken string.

Comment: That seems like a bug in the server. Do you have any access to the server?

Comment: Can you post the HTTP payload sent to the server by PHP and C#/.NET?

Comment: Unfortunately I do not have access to the server.

Comment: I requested the payload data from the PHP script